# The same value return different value with lodash

Tags: javascript, react-native, lodash

Case 1:

I set specify option value `selectedZone` to my `<DropDownMenu />` it works fine.

`<DropDownMenu />` is my selector:

```
  render() {
    let { zone, selectedZone, selectedCity } = this.state;

    return (
        <DropDownMenu
            style={{
              selectedOption: {
                marginBottom: -5
              }
            }}
            styleName="horizontal"
            options={zone}
            selectedOption={selectedZone || zone[0]}
            onOptionSelected={(zone) => {
                this.setState({ selectedZone: zone, selectedCity: zone.children[0] });
            }}
            titleProperty="brand"
            valueProperty="id"
        />

        ...
     )
   }
```

Case 2:

When I specify the value `selectedZone` from my AsyncStorage (The value is the same) it doesn't work and show yellow warnning.

So I try to check the source code.

The function `getSelectedOption()` from `<DropDownMenu />` source code.

```
  getSelectedOption() {
    const { options, selectedOption } = this.props;
    console.log('check options');
    console.log(options);
    console.log('check selectedOption');
    console.log(selectedOption);
    console.log('check _.indexOf(options, selectedOption');
    console.log(_.indexOf(options, selectedOption));
    if (_.indexOf(options, selectedOption) === -1) {
      console.warn(
        `Invalid \`selectedOption\` ${JSON.stringify(selectedOption)}, ` +
        'DropDownMenu `selectedOption` must be a member of `options`.' +
        'Check that you are using the same reference in both `options` and `selectedOption`.'
      );
      return;
    }
    return selectedOption;
  }
```

lodash function indexOf will return 1 in Case 1.

[image]

rerun -1 in Case 2,  I think it should return 1 just like Case 1

[image]

I compare with `options` and `selectedOption` can't see what is different in Case 1 and Case 2.

Some one can teach me what step I miss it ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`When I specify the value selectedZone from my AsyncStorage (The value is the same) it doesn't work and show yellow warnning.`

Lodash has very little to do with this - it comes down to how JavaScript compares objects - two of them are the same ONLY if they are literally the same underlying object:

```js
const a = {name: "fred"};
const b = a; //literally the same object
const c = {name: "fred"}; //an object that looks the same

console.log("a, b, c", a, b, c);
console.log("a === b", a === b); 
console.log("a === c", a === c);
```

Two objects with *the same values* which are *different objects* are not considered the same. At least, not according to `indexOf`, as it uses the JavaScript comparison:

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "alice"},
  {name: "bob"},
  {name: "carol"}
];

const originalObject = arr[1]; //literally the same object
const newObject = {name: "bob"}; //an object that looks the same

const indexWithOriginalObject = _.indexOf(arr, originalObject);
const indexWithNewObject = _.indexOf(arr, newObject);

console.log("index when using the original object:", indexWithOriginalObject);
console.log("index when using a new object that looks the same:", indexWithNewObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

However, you can use the Lodash method [`findIndex`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#findIndex) that will correctly do the comparison.

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "alice"},
  {name: "bob"},
  {name: "carol"}
];

const index = _.findIndex(arr, {name: "bob"});

console.log("index", index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

A word of warning - invoking `findIndex` with only an object will only check the properties you supplied. So it may not find the exact object you want, if you have more than one that look the same. You can use [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEqual) in a callback if you want to check that the two objects look EXACTLY the same

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "alice"},
  {name: "bob", lastName: "bloggs"},
  {name: "bob", lastName: "smith"},
  {name: "carol"}
];

const indexPartial1 = _.findIndex(arr, {name: "bob"});
const indexPartial2 = _.findIndex(arr, {name: "bob", lastName: "smith"});

const indexEqual1 = _.findIndex(arr, x => _.isEqual(x, {name: "bob"}));
const indexEqual2 = _.findIndex(arr,x => _.isEqual(x, {name: "bob", lastName: "smith"}));

console.log(
  "index by partial equality where the argument only has one property:", 
  indexPartial1
);
console.log(
  "index by partial equality where the argument has both properties:", 
  indexPartial2
);

console.log(
  "index by full equality where the argument only has one property:", 
  indexEqual1
);
console.log(
  "index by full equality where the argument has both properties:", 
  indexEqual2
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its very clear. Thank you @vlaz, I learn a lots from your answer !   I know how to fix my problem now. Thanks again.

Comment: Just made a small update to show one thing about `findIndex` that is worth knowing about. I don't know if you do need to check full equality but it's useful to know about it. It's probably more useful to do a partial match based on properties.